# FTSearch in Lotus Notes and wildcards

Tags: indexing, full-text-search, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a strange problem.....

Using this query string, I find 1 document

[ApplicantsForename] CONTAINS **ar*** AND [ApplicantsSurname] CONTAINS mcdermott

BUT using this string, simply making the wildcard part 1 character less, I find 0 documents. nb. The slight difference is the bold section

[ApplicantsForename] CONTAINS **a*** AND [ApplicantsSurname] CONTAINS mcdermott

Any idea why? Is there something where you have to use more than 1 character if using a wildcard or something stupid that I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Also, incase it gets suggested, we tried re-indexing the database last night.

Comment: What if you re-write request to: [ApplicantsForename] = *a* AND [ApplicantsSurname] CONTAINS mcdermott?

It's just looks weird using contains with wildcard.

Comment: Could you also set debug flag: Debug_FTV_Search=1 into notes.ini and post debug information (from console or log). That must help us to solve your issue.

Comment: Hi Dmytro,

Thanks for the suggestion, removing the wildcard and contains still returns 0 results, leaving contains and removing the wildcard also returns 0.

Let me speak to the admin about modifying the ini file

Comment: Try to add Debug flag and tell us a result. It may help.

Comment: Okay, looks like were getting an error.... F22

Any ideas? Output below

Query: ( FIELD ApplicantsForename CONTAINS  a* AND FIELD ApplicantsSurname CONTAINS  mcdermott)
Engine Query: ("a*"%STEM@F163 * "mcdermott"%STEM@F161)
 OUT FTGSearch error = F22

Comment: Have a look on this (pretty similar issue): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834687/notesdocumentcollection-ftsearch-and-a-search-query-with-special-characters

Comment: Thanks Dmytro, I aleady read that issue and tried playing with the quotes but still no resolution. Do we know what error F22 means? I cnt seem to find any information about it

Comment: IBM says it wont be fixed. The trick with replacing FTIndex form 7 to 8.5 ;) heh.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO41558

Comment: Hmmm, that APAR indicates an issue with 8.5 and that it works in 7...... This database we are having issues with is actually on a 7 server... Frustrating

Comment: Just to further confuse the issue, if I do a similar search for another document:

[ApplicantsForename] CONTAINS s* AND [ApplicantsSurname] CONTAINS marsh

This returns a result, so I can't put this down to an issue with single characters and wildcards!

Comment: Maybe you should try opening the doc that you should be finding with that search, making an inoccuous edit, re-saving, then re-building the indiex.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the suggestions, were still unable to resolve this so have told the user to use 2 characters with a wildcard which seems to work.....